# how to block ip in linux red hat 6?

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm trying to block the exit to another pc in my network. ultimately what I want to do is:

the machine "A" should not communicate with the machine "B"

and

the machine "B" should communicate with the machine "A"

I've achieved nothing, only do that no pc can communicate with the other, you know that I do?

You must be a command in linux, I've just found:

in the machine "A"

```
                      (ip machine "B")
iptables -I INPUT 1 -s 10.2.10.163 -j DROP
```

but I lose communication between the two

Comment: What do you mean by `communicate`? Do you want B to be able to open a tcp connection to A but not the other way around?

Comment: What I want to do is:

Pc "a" can ping pc "b"
but
Pc "b" can not ping pc "a"

Comment: Are you wanting `iptables` rules to be placed on machine A or machine B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment you want to block only `icmp` (ping), rule will be the following.

**Host A**

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -s ip_address_of_host_B -j DROP
```

Excluding `-s ip_address_of_host_B` will make all other IP's unavailable to ping host **A**.
Also, change *ip_address_of_host_B* to the actual IP address of host B.

Your rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -s 10.2.10.163 -j DROP
```

means: "Block all communication protocols (tcp/udp/icmp/etc) from source 10.2.10.163".

If you demand something else, let me know so I can update the answer.

Comment: thanks fugitive.

If I want to block tcp, just change icmp by tcp?

Comment: TCP is bidirectional, so no. You could block SYN packets so b could start a conversation with a but a could not start one with b, but once the communication is established then both can pass data.

Comment: thanks again, i find this command its works

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 10.1.10.171 --dport 1523 -j DROP`